# Protection from csrf

Tags: php, forms, csrf

I was trying to use the form key method for `csrf protection` here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys/ . But it applies on 1 form on a page only . My question is

Suppose i have a form

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<!-- code here -->
</form>
```

and My php i'm using

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
//do something
}
```

I'm already using `session user` to confirm he is logged in and and the form is being submitted by my site as session has been made on my site. Do i have to use csrf  protection method too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do i have to use csrf protection method too?

Yes, because this is exactly why CSRF is dangerous; the cookies of a "victim" are unknowingly sent to the server to perform a particular action on behalf of the "hacker" when they submit a modified form on another site, disguised by a cute kitten photo (for example).

When the disguised form is submitted, your site can't tell the request apart from a legit one, because the authentication will be valid. Adding a CSRF token makes sure that the form was submitted from a page on your site.

When the session is created you also generate a CSRF token. This token is then used for all the forms on your site for the duration of the session; doing this prevents problems with having multiple tabs open at the same time.

Even if the form is copied from your page, including a CSRF token, that token would be stored in a session that doesn't belong to an authenticated user.

Comment: Suppose i use session method where i generate a form key and send the key to php where it is validated. Now the problem is if the same page is opened in two tabs & the i refresh the new page and close it. `The sesion variable changes`. Now when i submit the form on first tab. It will always give error. Sometimes user do that `open same page in 2 tabs`. Is there any other safe method for csrf protection?

Comment: @user2894116 — Generate your token when the session is created, not every time the form is loaded.

Comment: @Jack apologies !! . This ajax method needs lot of code as i have a lot of forms on my page. Is here any other way with less code and same safety?

Comment: @Quentin sorry dint get that.I'm new to this. can u explain a lil pls ?

Comment: @user2894116 I've added a small explanation in the answer.

Comment: @Jack . Tell me if i understood it right. When the user logs in i create a token and whenever a from is submitted i validate that token

Comment: @user2894116 That's exactly it :)

Comment: @Jack Sorry for bothering you. Have a question. Should i send the generated token with the form and validate or can i validate it by taking the token session using $_SESSION['token'] , when there is submit request?

Comment: @Ace It needs to be part of the form.